# HiltViewModel: Cannot create an instance of class

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I am using Hilt. After updating to `1.0.0-alpha03` I got warnings that `@ViewModelInject` is deprecated and I should use `@HiltViewModel`. But when I change it I got an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.LoginViewModel
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.LoginViewModel.<init> [class android.app.Application]
```

Previous my ViewModel looked like this:

```kotlin
class LoginViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    application: Application,
    private val repository: RealtimeDatabaseRepository
) : AndroidViewModel(application)
```

Now it looks like this:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
    application: Application,
    private val repository: RealtimeDatabaseRepository
) : AndroidViewModel(application)
```

Fragment where ViewModel is injected:

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class LoginFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_login)
{
    private val viewModel: LoginViewModel by activityViewModels()
}
```

Injected class:

```kotlin
@Singleton
class RealtimeDatabaseRepository @Inject constructor() { }
```

When I deleted `private val repository: RealtimeDatabaseRepository` from ViewModel constructor it is working

---

I was using hilt version `2.30.1-alpha` when I updated to `2.31.2-alpha`, as [USMAN osman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12397978/usman-osman) suggested, the error is gone.

Comment: does your activity have `@AndroidEntryPoint` too? Also, you don't need a `@Provides` method for classes that have an `@Inject` constructor annotation

Comment: Yes, Activity has `@AndroidEntryPoint`. But if I want my repository to be a singleton I don't have to make `@Provides`? Can I annotate a class with `@Singleton` and it will be enough?

Comment: yes, you can annotate classes with a scope annotations `@Singleton class RealtimeDatabaseRepository @Inject constructor() { }`

Comment: Okay, thanks. I deleted provide function but the error is still the same

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With new hilt version lots of stuff has been changed.
You also have to upgrade your hilt android, hilt compiler and hilt gradle plugin to:`2.31-alpha`
I made mock sample exactly the way you did i had same issue, after going through hilt's docs i found new way to inject dependencies to viewModels, you have to make separate module for dependencies which are going to inject in the `viewModel` with special component called `ViewModelComponent`:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class) // this is new
object RepositoryModule{

    @Provides
    @ViewModelScoped // this is new
    fun providesRepo(): ReposiotryIMPL { // this is just fake repository
        return ReposiotryIMPL()
    }

}
```

here is what docs says about `ViewModelComponent` and `ViewModelScoped`

`All Hilt View Models are provided by the ViewModelComponent which follows the same lifecycle as a ViewModel, i.e. it survives configuration changes. To scope a dependency to a ViewModel use the @ViewModelScoped annotation.`

`A @ViewModelScoped type will make it so that a single instance of the scoped type is provided across all dependencies injected into the Hilt View Model.`
link: https://dagger.dev/hilt/view-model.html

then your viewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class RepoViewModel @Inject constructor(
    application: Application,
    private val reposiotryIMPL: ReposiotryIMPL
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {}
```

**UPDATE**
It is not mandatory that you should be using `ViewModelComponent` or `ViewModelScoped` as i did in the above example. You can also use other `scopes` or `components` depends on your usecase.
Furthermore read docs, i put the dagger-hilt's link above.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now. The only thing I had to do was to update dependencies to `2.31-alpha`

Comment: Omg, I forgot to update the kapt and I struggled like 5 hours finding the solution to why this is not working ... after reading the answer 5 times I figured it out, triple check the versions if your app crash

Comment: it is fine to use a @Singleton scope as well, if you want to outlive the ViewModel:
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)

Comment: I can confirm that updating the dependencies is sometimes the only thing missing to make the error go away. The `hilt-android` and `hilt-android-compiler` need to have the same version.

Answer (score 11):

I've seen this happens when the **Fragment/Activity** that is using the ViewModel is missing the ***@AndroidEntryPoint*** annotation, for instance:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels

@AndroidEntryPoint
class SampleFragment: BaseFragment() {
     val viewModel: SampleFragmentViewModel by viewModels()
}
```

If the annotation is not present, the exact same error you describe will happen.

Answer (score 2):

My error was a dumb one which might help future people, adding a ViewModel to a feature module I forgot to add the `kapt` and `hilt` dependencies to the feature's `build.gradle` file, meaning Hilt would never see the ViewModel.